# Formula for normalizing data

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, normalization

I have four groups of treated animals data, Wildtype age 3 months, Knock our age 3 months,  Wildtype age 6months, and Knockout age 6 months. I need to normalize all the data to the untreated  Wildtype age 3 months old. What is the best formula to use?

Comment: Welcome to this forum! Consider taking a tour: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour . Hope this will help!

Answer (score 2):

Say you have some variable X ranging from 1 to n, so $\{x_1 , \dots x_n\}$.

If you want to normalize your data (which i presume for you means making it between 0 and 1) then you simply do the following:

$$y_i = \frac{x_i-min(X)}{max(X) - min(X)}$$

And Y will be your new normalized variable.

Maybe you want it to have mean 0 and standard deviation 1 in which case you can do:

$$y_i = \frac{x_i - \bar{x}}{\sigma}$$

Where $\bar{x}$ is the mean of X and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of X

Comment: Thanks rannoudanames. I am still confused. In the two formulas you mentioned above, which symbol represents the control that I should normilzed my data to?